# Reshaping (Flattening) Images into Column Vectors Arrangementt

Tags: python, numpy, vector, deep-learning, reshape

Given I have a set of 200 64x64 images of carrots. If I am to take one of these images, say n1, and reshape n1 (n1 has a shape of (64,64,3)) to a column vector. Will the output column vector be vertically sorted by the RGB values present in n1.

(Please check [here](https://necromuralist.github.io/neural_networks/posts/image-to-vector/image2vector_kiank.png) to understand what I mean by vertically sorted by RGB)

Please see, the bit of python code I am using to reshape the carrot Image is given below:

`n1Reshaped = n1.reshape((n1.shape[0]*n1.shape[1]*n1.shape[2]), 1)`

Comment: Did you look at the contents of n1Reshaped to see if it is what you want?

Comment: Hello I did get a feature column vector, but I don't understand what features this new vector, represents. When it was in it's original form it was clearly organized as RGB values per pixel. Now in its feature column state, are the features still pixels and how are they arranged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution as an explanation. It is a mental model and is long and drawn out. So [Here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning/discussions/all/threads/AFGO6sxZEeelvwo0WJS8jA/replies/NzRuAkKAEei4bA6tOIIF_g?utm_medium=email&utm_source=other&utm_campaign=opencourse.discourse.neural-networks-deep-learning~opencourse.discourse.W_mOXCrdEeeNPQ68_4aPpA.AFGO6sxZEeelvwo0WJS8jA~NzRuAkKAEei4bA6tOIIF_g)